# Find last two characters in a list of words

Tags: python-3.x

I wonder how I could make a function that returns the last to characters of each of the words in a list of words. Here's what I am thinking:

```
mylist = ["Hello","there","people"]

def two(s):
    for element in s:
        letters = element[2:-1]
    return(letters)


print(two(mylist))
```

What I want printed out is "lorele"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a list comprehension or a generator expression, and using `join`:

```
mylist = ["Hello","there","people"]

def two(s):
    return ''.join(i[-2:] for i in s)

>>> two(mylist)
'lorele'
```

Alternatively, to fix your code, which is *almost* working:

```
def two(s):
    # Initialize letters as an empty string:
    letters = ''
    # Append last two letters for each element:
    for element in s:
        # Proper indexing is [-2:], which takes from the second to last character to the end of each element
        letters += element[-2:]
    return(letters)
```

Note: Don't use `list` as a variable name, as it masks python's built-in type. I changed it to `mylist` in the example above, and edited your question to reflect that too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I usually use my native language name for "list" and forgot about it when I translated it into english, but thanks for the heads up anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is your friend

```
>>> a=["hello",'world','how','are','you!']
>>> '12345'[-2:]
'45'
>>> b=[mine[-2:] for mine in a]
>>> b
['lo', 'ld', 'ow', 're', 'u!']
>>> "".join(b)
'loldowreu!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you **cannot** use *the reserved words* as variable names.

With **your code:**

```
l = ["Hello","there","people"]

def two(s):
    letters = ''
    for element in s:
        letters += element[-2:]
    return letters

print(two(l))
```

With **list comprehension:**

```
print(''.join([s[-2:] for s in ["Hello","there","people"]]))
```